# JavaFX 8 - Add a graphic to a TitledPane on the right side

Tags: java, layout, javafx-8

I want to add a little icon to the title of a `TitledPane`. Therefore I set an empty title and add a `HBox` containing a `Label` and a `ImageView` as graphic. In this way the icon is shown close to the end of the text. I want it to be shown always next to the right border of the `TitledPane`.
How can I do this?
I also tried to use a `BorderPane` and add the `Label` to the center and the `ImageView` to the right, but the `BorderPane` doesn't get the maximum size of the TitledPane.
So I tried to set MaxWidth to Max-Value, but this didn't help

Does anybody know what to do?

**EDIT: ** The "custom" control I created will be initialized within a method called in stage.setOnShown.

```
public class CustomTitledPane extends TitledPane {
private Image alert;
private Image registered;
private Image deleted;
private ImageView img;

public CustomTitledPane(String titleText, Node node) {
    super(titleText, node);
    setAnimated(true);
    setCollapsible(true);
    img = new ImageView();
    img.setFitHeight(10d);
    img.setPreserveRatio(true);
    img.setSmooth(true);
    setGraphic(img);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    // apply css and force layout of nodes
    applyCss();
    layout();

    // title region
    Node titleRegion = lookup(".title");
    // padding
    Insets padding = ((StackPane) titleRegion).getPadding();
    // image width
    double graphicWidth = img.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    // arrow
    double arrowWidth = titleRegion.lookup(".arrow-button")
            .getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
    // text
    double labelWidth = titleRegion.lookup(".text").getLayoutBounds()
            .getWidth();

    double nodesWidth = graphicWidth + padding.getLeft()
            + padding.getRight() + arrowWidth + labelWidth;
    System.out.println("w: " + graphicWidth + " " + arrowWidth + " "
            + labelWidth);
    graphicTextGapProperty().bind(widthProperty().subtract(nodesWidth));
    try {
        alert = new Image(new FileInputStream("img/Alert.png"));
        registered = new Image(new FileInputStream("img/Registered.png"));
        deleted = new Image(new FileInputStream("img/Deleted.png"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

And here's the CSS for TitledPane:

```
    .titled-pane {
    -fx-text-fill: #006FD8;
}

.titled-pane > .title {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, grey 30%, grey 70%, white 100%) transparent transparent transparent;
}

.titled-pane:expanded > .title {
    -fx-border-color: grey transparent transparent transparent;
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DCE7F5, white);
}

.titled-pane:expanded > *.content {
    -fx-border-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code shown by the OP on his edited question, this code addresses the fact that the titled pane is created on a listener before the stage is shown, on a custom class.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
        CustomTitledPane customTitledPane = new CustomTitledPane("Title", new StackPane(new Label("Graphic to the Right")));
        scene.setRoot(customTitledPane);
        customTitledPane.applyCss();
        customTitledPane.layout();

        // title region
        Node titleRegion=customTitledPane.lookup(".title");
        // padding
        Insets padding=((StackPane)titleRegion).getPadding();
        // image width
        double graphicWidth=customTitledPane.getGraphic().getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        // arrow
        double arrowWidth=titleRegion.lookup(".arrow-button").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        // text
        double labelWidth=titleRegion.lookup(".text").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

        double nodesWidth = graphicWidth+padding.getLeft()+padding.getRight()+arrowWidth+labelWidth;

        customTitledPane.graphicTextGapProperty().bind(customTitledPane.widthProperty().subtract(nodesWidth));
    });

    primaryStage.show();

}

class CustomTitledPane extends TitledPane {

    public CustomTitledPane(String titleText, Node node) {
        super(titleText, node);
        setAnimated(true);
        setCollapsible(true);
        ImageView img = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("unlock24.png").toExternalForm()));
        img.setFitHeight(10d);
        img.setPreserveRatio(true);
        img.setSmooth(true);
        setGraphic(img);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
    }
}
```

Comment: But when I have another Node(s) on the scene I can't set the root of the scene to the titledPane or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm using the root for simplicity. You just need to add your titledPane as a child to the proper container.

Comment: Sorry, but there is still one problem. When I collapse the TitledPane it gets wider everytime. Same issue when I close the TitledPane. How is this possible??

Comment: I can't tell, it doesn't happen to me. Do your images have the same width? Print to console all the values from `setOnShown` and see which is changing, and also add a listener to `customTitledPane.widthProperty()`. Or use ScenicView to track these changes.

Comment: I figured out that the only thing changing is the `widthProperty` of the `TitledPane`. Everything else stays. So I tried working with a listener on the `widthProperty` of the `TitledPane` with `setGraphicTextGap(getWidth() - nodesWidth)` but the result is the same. The width is also growing when I resize the columns of the `TableView` within the `TitledPane`.

Comment: Then the problem is not the rendering of the title region! The problems are: your titled pane is in a container which allows it to be resized; the content makes it grow. In this case, use a `ScrollPane` to wrap the content. Also you could set the size (min/pref/max) for the titled pane.

Comment: Thank you. I just setManaged(true) for the Child Node. Now it works fine!

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to wrap graphic and text in a box, since you can select how to display your content with `setContentDisplay()`:

```
title.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

Once you have the image at the right you need to set the gap between the image and the text. For that, we can use some lookups to get the real dimensions of the nodes in the title, once the stage is shown.

Finally, we bind the gap space to the width property of the title subtracting those dimensions.

**EDIT**

The sample now supports creation before the stage is shown.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(), 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
        TitledPane title = new TitledPane("Title",
                new StackPane(new Label("Graphic to the Right")));

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResource("unlock24.png").toExternalForm()));

        title.setGraphic(imageView);
        title.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

        scene.setRoot(title);

        // apply css and force layout of nodes
        title.applyCss();
        title.layout();

        // title region
        Node titleRegion=title.lookup(".title");
        // padding
        Insets padding=((StackPane)titleRegion).getPadding();
        // image width
        double graphicWidth=imageView.getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        // arrow
        double arrowWidth=titleRegion.lookup(".arrow-button").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        // text
        double labelWidth=titleRegion.lookup(".text").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();

        double nodesWidth = graphicWidth+padding.getLeft()+padding.getRight()+arrowWidth+labelWidth;  

        title.graphicTextGapProperty().bind(title.widthProperty().subtract(nodesWidth));
    });

    primaryStage.show();

}
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: Titled Pane]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but I get a `NullPointerException` at  `.getPadding()` and every `.lookup()` method?

Comment: `lookup` tries to find a CSS selector. It returns a Node or null if the selector is not found. Are you applying custom CSS to your titledPane? Then you should look for your selectors. Anyway, try to run my sample and check if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, I'm applying a custom CSS, but this can't be the problem, because your sample works fine with it in a testapplication. So what else could causing the NullPointerException?

Comment: First, the `lookup` has to be called after the stage has been shown. Even if you apply a custom selector to your `TitledPane`, look for this `.title`, since this is the selector from the `TitleRegion` child. Do you know about [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/)? It will help you finding your selectors.

Comment: The TitledPane will be created within a method called after the Stage is shown (stage.setOnShown). So everything should be good? Didn't know about ScenicView. I'll try it with that.

Comment: That's the problem... you have to define the listener before the stage is shown, but at that time the lookups will fail. You can call `title.applyCss()`, and you won't get a NPE, but all widths will be 0.

Comment: Still get a NPE. I'll update the question with some code and CSS I use.

Comment: You need an Scene to layout the nodes... I've added another answer with a working solution.