# JavaFX DatePicker with multiple choice

Tags: javafx, calendar

I need to choose more than one date from calendar. Is there some useful component? I've tried to use https://kenai.com/projects/jfxcalendarpicker/pages/Home in multiple mode, but it has some critical bugs for me.

Comment: What prevents you from using two or more `DatePicker`s?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229168/selecting-a-period-or-a-date-using-one-javafx-8-datepicker/27231422#27231422) uses one `DatePicker` to allow the selection of a range of dates

Comment: @eckig I need to choose array of dates through all the year. DatePicker gives us only one date. I need indeterminate number of dates and store them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select multiple dates with DatePicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571764/select-multiple-dates-with-datepicker)