# Highlighting multiple days on Javafx datepickerskin

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I am trying create a small app that lets the user do the following:

- enter a date in a textfield in the format dd/mm/yyyy
- press a button
- display the date selected and highlight it plus the previous 5 days on one datepickerskin.

I understood I have to use cell factory and I found several implementations on stackoverflow and other websites, however none work in my case, hence my question. I have seen different ways to achieve what I want, with and without arrays, the one I decided to post seems to be the more elegant.

I don't understand whether my code doesn't work or for whatever reason the code can't override the default theme.

I am also experiencing another issue: if I don’t set the daycellfactory the user can use the app entering several dates once a time and the button works, if I set a daycellfactory the button works only once, what can I do?

This is the logic of my button:

```
  calculate_button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            //getting user input as string
            String user_date = textField_start_of_period.getText();
            //checking that the user input is in the format dd/mm/yyyy:
            String regex_check = "[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{4}";
            if (user_date.matches(regex_check)) {
                //transforming string into time
                DateTimeFormatter datetimeformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(user_date, datetimeformatter);

                //setting the entered date
                today.setValue(localDate.plusDays(13));

                //array with days I want to be highlited (today -days)
                List<LocalDate> fertile_days = new ArrayList<>();
                highlight_days.add(today.getValue().minusDays(5)); 
                highlight_days.add(today.getValue().minusDays(4)); 
                highlight_days.add(today.getValue().minusDays(3)); 
               
                //highlighting days
                final Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> dayCellFactory = new Callback<>() {
                    @Override
                    public DateCell call(final DatePicker datePicker) {
                        return new DateCell() {
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (!empty && item != null) {
                                    if (highlight_days.contains(item)) {
                                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };

                today.setDayCellFactory(dayCellFactory);

   } else {
                String errormessage = new String("error");
                textField_start_of_period.setText(errormessage);
            }
        });
```

I tried changing different formats in the array:

```
highlight_days.add(LocalDate.now().minusDays(5));
highlight_days.add(LocalDate.of(2024,Month.JANUARY,5));
```

I tried setting the daycellfactory directly but it also doesn't work:

```
   today.setDayCellFactory(new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
                    @Override
                    public DateCell call(DatePicker param) {
                        return new DateCell(){
                            @Override
                            public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                                if (!empty && item != null) {
                                    if(highlight.contains(item)) {
                                        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink");
//I thought maybe the default theme was overriding my code so I tried:
                                      //this.getStyleClass().add("hightlight_days"); *
//but it doesn’t work
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });
```

*This is the code in stylesheet.css (placed in src/main/resources):

```
.date-picker-popup > * > .date-cell.highlight_days {
  -fx-background-color: pink;
}
```

The Datepicker today is the same shown when the user opens the app and shows the current day (LocalDate.now) and it is reused once the user clicks the button:

```
DatePicker today = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(today);  
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();
```

This is done because DatePickerSkin only shows one day by default so when the user launch the app there must be a day selected (I can’t leave the DatePickerSkin constructor empty). Using different DatePickers doesn’t work as DatePickerSkin accepts only one DatePicker which means adding more DatePickers means adding more DatePickersSkins and then having to show them with multiple Nodes which I have to add to the grid, so either I don’t show the DatePickerSkin when the user opens the app or I add multiple which I don’t want.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See if the following can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571764/select-multiple-dates-with-datepicker

Comment: There are a number of issues with your `DateCell` implementations. The `updateItem(...)` method must set the style appropriately in all code paths. Cells are (potentially) reused for different dates, so you must set the style to a default if the highlight does not apply. (Else a cell may retain the highlight style when it is not supposed to be highlighted.) Conversely, you can't guarantee that a cell's `updateItem(...)` method will be called when the date picker's value changes, so your cells should ensure the style is updated when the value changes.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing with the `DatePickerSkin`. Are you trying to show the popup content without showing the actual `DatePicker`?

Comment: @SedJ601 Thanks unfortunately I tried but couldn't adapt that code to my case I think because I want to show DatePickerSkin

Comment: @James_D the coder for the datepicker is below in my first post but in my code it is above the button's logic. The DatePickerSkin shows today as LocaleDate.Now and I am reusing today in my button's logic. I tried creating other DatePickers but If I do that they need to be added to new DatePickerSkins and then somehow added instead of DatePickerSkin which displays today.

I am using updateItem() only once in my app in the button's logic. I tried changing the default style with a stylesheet but it doesn't work. Apologies if I am not understanding your reply properly but I am still learning.

Comment: Would a number of distinct [`DateCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DateCell.html) instances be an alternative?

Comment: It’s really still not clear to me what you’re doing. Controls (such as `DatePicker`) have a `Skin` which determines how the control is displayed. You don’t usually interact with the skin, and typically only do so to replace them to change the way the control is displayed. You seem to be doing something different? Create and post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D I am using DatePickerSkin to display the calendar all the time

Comment: Ok, but that is a completely separate concern from proper highlighting of the cells, isn’t it? I would just get the highlighting working as you want in the usual context, before trying to use the control in a way that isn’t really supported by the API. Ask just one question per post.

Comment: In my question I thought I had been clear that I was trying to highlight the days in a skin because I wanted to display the calendar part all the time, seems I wasn't clear. I will check the question you linked, should I try the first or second solution?Do you think it would work with DatePickerSkin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for two completely different things here. First, you want to highlight the five days preceding the selected date in a `DatePicker`, and second, you want to use the internal calendar used by the `DatePicker` as a separate control. This answer addresses the first (with a hint about the second, though that is not tested).

This approach uses a custom CSS pseudoclass to indicate the highlight. The `style.css` file is simply

```
.date-cell:fertile {
    -fx-background-color: pink;
}
```

The date picker cell just needs to set the pseudoclass state depending on whether the date represented by the cell is within the correct range relative to the selected date (the `value`). Note this means you must update this pseudoclass state if either the date represented by the cell changes (which you can do from `updateItem(...)` in the usual way) or when the selected item changes (which you can do with a listener). Here is a basic implementation:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class App
        extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
        final int precedingDays = 5;
        picker.setDayCellFactory(p -> new DateCell() {
            PseudoClass fertile = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("fertile");
            {
                picker.valueProperty().addListener(obs -> updateStyle(getItem()));
            }
            @Override
            public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(date, empty);
                updateStyle(date);
            }

            private void updateStyle(LocalDate date) {
                LocalDate selected = picker.getValue();
                if (date == null || selected == null) {
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(fertile, false);
                } else {
                    long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date, selected);
                    pseudoClassStateChanged(fertile, days > 0 && days < precedingDays);
                }
            }
        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(picker);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(60));

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setTitle("Preceding Days DatePicker");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For displaying the calendar as a popup all the time, you can try replacing

```
BorderPane root = new BorderPane(picker);
```

with

```
DatePickerSkin skin = new DatePickerSkin(picker);
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(skin.getPopupContent());
```

but note this is not (as far as I am aware) a supported use of the API.

Comment: Yes it is exactly what I am trying to achieve, I knew that extracting the calendar part of DatePicker wasn't part of the standard API but I had found the solution on stackoverflow and it seemed straightforward so I used it, I didn't realize it would add complexity, I was just trying to avoid using external libraries and the calendar of DatePicker fits my needs just right. I will try your code and let you know.

Comment: Definitely works better than mine.  Though I think the day test should be `days > 0 && days <= precedingDays`, so five previous days are pink and the selection is the default selection color.

Comment: @VGR Agreed; I updated it.

Comment: It worked great, Thanks a lot James_D for the solution and for the others for attempting.

Answer (score 3):

I’m not sure what the point of messing with the Skin would be.  There is no need to do so.

If I understand your task correctly, you just want to show the days preceding the selected date in a different color.  You can do that in a DateCell, but one extra step is needed:  you must also tell the DatePicker to re-render every cell whenever the selected date changes:

```
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
picker.setDayCellFactory(p -> new PrecedingDaysDateCell(p));
picker.valueProperty().addListener(o -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
    picker.setDayCellFactory(null);
    picker.setDayCellFactory(p -> new PrecedingDaysDateCell(p));
}));
```

The above code responds to any change in the DatePicker’s `value` property by setting the cell factory to null (the default), then back to a cell factory which renders days in pink, causing every date cell to be re-rendered.  It’s clumsy, but effective.

(The Platform.runLater call is necessary because changing the cell factory while the DatePicker is still processing the value change can lead to internal inconsistencies that result in exceptions.)

This seems to work for me in all circumstances:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Objects;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.control.DateCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

// For App class only
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class PrecedingDaysDateCell
extends DateCell {
    private final DatePicker picker;

    private final int precedingDays;

    private final Background precedingDaysBackground = new Background(
        new BackgroundFill(Color.PINK, null, null));

    public PrecedingDaysDateCell(DatePicker picker) {
        this(picker, 5);
    }

    public PrecedingDaysDateCell(DatePicker picker,
                                 int precedingDays) {

        this.picker = Objects.requireNonNull(picker,
            "DatePicker cannot be null.");

        this.precedingDays = precedingDays;
    }

    private void updateBackground(LocalDate date) {
        LocalDate selectedDate = picker.getValue();
        if (date != null && selectedDate != null) {
            long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date, selectedDate);
            if (days > 0 && days <= precedingDays) {
                setBackground(precedingDaysBackground);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(LocalDate date,
                           boolean empty) {

        super.updateItem(date, empty);

        if (!empty) {
            updateBackground(date);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
        if (!selected) {
            updateBackground(getItem());
        }
    }

    public static class App
    extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) {
            DatePicker picker = new DatePicker();
            picker.setDayCellFactory(p -> new PrecedingDaysDateCell(p));
            picker.valueProperty().addListener(o -> Platform.runLater(() -> {
                picker.setDayCellFactory(null);
                picker.setDayCellFactory(p -> new PrecedingDaysDateCell(p));
            }));

            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane(picker);
            pane.setPadding(new Insets(60));

            stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
            stage.setTitle("Preceding Days DatePicker");
            stage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and works as I wanted! However it does not use DatePickerSkin so when the date is selected the calendar part disappears, I thought I was clear in why I was using DatePickerSkin but it seems I wasn't so apologies.

Comment: If you want to let the user select multiple days, I would look at SedJ601’s link.  I personally would not attempt this at all;  DatePicker extends ComboBoxBase and is designed to produce one and only one value at any given time.  I would write an entirely new compound control for letting a user enter multiple dates.  I probably would make use of a ListView to display the dates, a DatePicker to choose a date to add to the list, and Buttons for adding dates to and removing dates from the list.

Comment: I tried to adapt your code:

TextField textField = new TextField();
String user_date = textField.getText();

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(user_date,dateTimeFormatter);
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(localDate);

DatePickerSkin datePickerSkin = new DatePickerSkin(picker);
Node popupContent = datePickerSkin.getPopupContent();

and set CellFactory as you did but it throws an exception in the Application start method. How can I get the date from a textinputfield and user your code in the skin?

Comment: The user would need to select just one day but through a textfield and the highlighted days would use your code but on a datepickerskin so the calendar part is always visibile

Comment: I see.  Exactly what user actions should cause the popup to be hidden?

Comment: When the user selects a date with the picker the calendar part disappears to make it always visible I understood you should use DatePickerSkin which is what I did

Comment: You want it to be always visible?  Even if the user is using other text fields or buttons?  Even if the user switches to another application?

Comment: Setting and resetting the cell factory when the value changes seems like a bit of a hack (especially since it requires a `Platform.runLater(…)` call).  You should be able just to do `picker.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldDate, newDate) -> updateBackground(getItem()));` in the cell constructor.

Comment: @James_D It is definitely a hack.  But I think it at least doesn’t rely on undocumented behavior and should work consistently.  The problem with only updating the background of the current item is that it won’t update the date cells for the five days preceding the last selected value.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work correctly at all. If you navigate through the months, the incorrect cells are highlighted. This simply isn't the correct approach.

Comment: *"The problem with only updating the background of the current item is that it won’t update the date cells for the five days preceding the last selected value."* But it wouldn't only be updating the background of the current item.

Comment: @James_D Darn it, you’re right about changing months. I honestly thought I had checked that.  I don’t think listening to valueProperty will be enough to compensate for that.  In fact, I’m not sure anything can compensate for that, short of relying on undocumented internals…

Comment: You don't need anything special here. Just use the standard API. See my solution.