# DateCell not changing, after applying "selected" Style

Tags: java, css, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

I have a DatePicker and add this Listener.

```
datePicker.showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, showing) -> {
        if(showing) {
            //Get the content
            DatePickerContent content = (DatePickerContent)((DatePickerSkin)datePicker.getSkin()).getPopupContent();
            content.lookupAll(".day-cell").forEach(cell -> { 
                cell.getStyleClass().add("selected");
                System.out.println(cell.getStyleClass() + " Day: " + ((DateCell) cell).getItem());
            });
        }
    });
```

But after showing the DatePicker and selecting a date, only one cell is shown as being selected.

[image: DatePicker with one day selected]

Even tough the styles printed out in the console all have "selected", but what keeps me wondering, that the Cell which is really selected has 2 "selected" styles.
This is Console output (part of it):

```
cell date-cell day-cell selected Day: 2017-07-11
cell date-cell day-cell selected Day: 2017-07-12
cell date-cell day-cell selected selected Day: 2017-07-13
cell date-cell day-cell selected Day: 2017-07-14
cell date-cell day-cell selected Day: 2017-07-15
```

So why is only one Cell being displayed as selected?

Comment: I don't know how to link other questions, and neither can find any resources on that in the webs...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27229168/selecting-a-period-or-a-date-using-one-javafx-8-datepicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add a listener to the property, just set `datePicker.onShown`.

```
//Get the content
datePicker.onShown(e -> {
        DatePickerContent content = (DatePickerContent)((DatePickerSkin)datePicker.getSkin()).getPopupContent();
        content.lookupAll(".day-cell").forEach(cell -> { 
            cell.getStyleClass().add("selected");
        });
}
```