# JavaFX 11: Add a graphic to a TitledPane on the right side

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-11

This is related to a previous question asked over three years ago.
[JavaFX 8 - Add a graphic to a TitledPane on the right side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100556/javafx-8-add-a-graphic-to-a-titledpane-on-the-right-side)

I do not like this solution, and I haven't found any other solutions.

A lot has happened to JavaFX since this original question was asked for JavaFX 8. Recently JavaFX 11 was released.

I have a project using JavaFX 11.
The TitledPane graphic is set with a HBox containing a single Button I want placed at the far right side of the title.

```
TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
titledPane.setText("Title");

HBox titleBox = new HBox();
Button b1 = new Button("ClickMe!");
titleBox.getChildren().add(b1);

titledPane.setGraphic(titleBox);
titledPane.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);
```

Setting the TitlePane Alignment to CENTER_RIGHT will place the title to the right, but the entire title, text and graphic.

```
titledPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
```

I have tried experimenting with different containers in the TitledPane graphic, HBox, GridPane. Setting grow, alignment, fillWidth, etc. None works.

Without setting an artificial graphic gap, I see no viable solutions, but the hack suggested in the referenced question above.
It is an ugly hack. 
For multiple TitledPanes in an Acrodion. However the Button is not placed at the exact end, there is still more room to the right on the title.

```java
primaryStage.setOnShown(e -> {
    for (TitledPane titledPane : panes) {
        Node titleRegion = titledPane.lookup(".title");
        Insets padding = ((StackPane) titleRegion).getPadding();
        double graphicWidth = titledPane.getGraphic().getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        double arrowWidth = titleRegion.lookup(".arrow-button").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        double labelWidth = titleRegion.lookup(".text").getLayoutBounds().getWidth();
        double nodesWidth = graphicWidth + padding.getLeft() + padding.getRight() + arrowWidth + labelWidth;
        titledPane.graphicTextGapProperty().bind(titledPane.widthProperty().subtract(nodesWidth));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your goal, but I believe you want the TitledPane to have both a `Label` and a `Button` with the `Label` left-aligned and the `Button` right-aligned, correct?

In order to do that, does require a little bit of a workaround and use of JavaFX's containers. First of all, no need to set a title for the `TitledPane` itself; we will add a `Label` to our graphic to serve as the title.

In the example below, we will use a `HBox` to hold all of the nodes we want within the `TitledPane`. Within the `HBox`, we add a `Region` that is set to always grow within the `HBox`. This forces the `Button` all the way to the right.

Then, since the `TitledPane` has a semi-fixed max width for its graphic, we need to bind our `HBox` to the width of the `TitledPane`, with padding to avoid overlapping the "expand" arrow.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple interface
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create the TitlePane
        TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane();
        titledPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create HBox to hold our Title and button
        HBox contentPane = new HBox();
        contentPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Set padding on the left side to avoid overlapping the TitlePane's expand arrow
        // We will also pad the right side
        contentPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 35));

        // Now, since the TitlePane's graphic node generally has a fixed size, we need to bind our
        // content pane's width to match the width of the TitledPane. This will account for resizing as well
        contentPane.minWidthProperty().bind(titledPane.widthProperty());

        // Create a Region to act as a separator for the title and button
        HBox region = new HBox();
        region.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        HBox.setHgrow(region, Priority.ALWAYS);

        // Add our nodes to the contentPane
        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Titles Are Cool"),
                region,
                new Button("Click me!")
        );

        // Add the contentPane as the graphic for the TitledPane
        titledPane.setGraphic(contentPane);

        // Add the pane to our root layout
        root.getChildren().add(titledPane);

        // Show the Stage
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **The Result:**

[image: Screenshot]

This is a fairly clean solution and I would not consider it to be a "hack". Just using the containers and structures of JavaFX as they were intended.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. That is exactly what I was trying for.
I tried something similar my self, using a HBox, but was unsuccessful. I think your trick with the Region was the missing link. Though I had to increase the padding left because the title was under the arrow. In my case I set font-size 28px, so the padding need to take that into account. I am accepting the answer, but shame there isn't a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use containers for graphic node - just translate it to the right:

```
TitledPane titledPane = new TitledPane("Title", null);
titledPane.setPrefSize(400, 200);

Button graphic = new Button("Click me!");
titledPane.setGraphic(graphic);
titledPane.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.RIGHT);

final double graphicMarginRight = 10; //change it, if needed

graphic.translateXProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(
    () -> titledPane.getWidth() - graphic.getLayoutX() - graphic.getWidth() - graphicMarginRight,
    titledPane.widthProperty())
);
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Interesting solution. The only problem is the graphicMarginRight. For a font-size of 28px, I needed it set to 125.

Comment: I used "10px" just as an example, you can pick any other value or compute it to suit your needs (e.g. as a function of font size if you need it to imitate padding in em units).